# How do I stop facebook from turning my pictures literally Red/Orange

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, color-management, facebook

Every time I edit pictures from shoots I get them to the exact pale way I want them in photoshop, I have tried saving the images as Jpeg, PNG and Tiff. I always do 2048 for size, but facebook always turns my images literally red on mobile devices, color setting is at RGB in photoshop. Please help. I cannot find anything helpful online thus far.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Are you uploading from a desktop or mobile?

Comment: how many mobile devices?  what OS?  etc.

Comment: When you say "color setting is at RGB", do you mean _Adobe RGB_?

Answer (score 2):

in PS, use **Save for Web and Devices**, check the box **Convert to sRGB**.